# Is it possible to create function inside `conf.js`?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, automated-tests

Is it possible to create function which is used for every spec to test, for example login function inside the `conf.js` file or directly `sendKeys` from `conf.js` as from `spec.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From nodejs syntax, it supports to do that as following:

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
   // put config at here as usual
};

exports.login = function(username, password) {

  browser.get('');
  element.sendKeys('');
};

// spec.js

var login = require('./conf.js').login;
// actually, you can move the login function to another .js file to keep
// conf.js more dedicated on configuration purpose.

describe("A spec (with setup and tear-down)", function() {

   it('', function(){
       login('username', 'password')
   });

});
```

But that is not a good practice. Because main test framework supports to do something before each test case. For jasmine it supplys `beforeEach`:

```
describe("A spec (with setup and tear-down)", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = 0;
    foo += 1;
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    foo = 0;
  });

  it("is just a function, so it can contain any code", function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(1);
  });

  it("can have more than one expectation", function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(1);
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

At last, I can't see the benefit/advantage to do as you required.

Comment: just a silly question tho is `beforeEach` function will get call once only or before each function

Comment: thanks i implemented above mentioned solution and it worked

Comment: `beforeEach()` will be called before each  `it()` function be executed.

Comment: If you login in `beforeEach()`, you can do logout in `afterEach()`.  Or you can only use `beforeEach()` with following process:  1) do logout no matter is login or not, 2) do login

Comment: can be set `beforeEach` to get called for very first `it()` only

Comment: You can't.  If you want the code lines inside `beforeEach()` are executed for only one time, you can move that code lines into a separate `it()` and put this `it()` at the top of all `it()`.